# How to show html texts in Android WebView in proper format?

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I have a string which contains html texts and images parsed from a json file.I need to show it in `webview`.The string consists of 3-4 paragraph but while displaying in `webview` it shows like one paragraph i.e the android `webview` skips the breakline tags.But my requirement is to show as it is in the website with proper alignment.Please help me.

my Json file link is [this](http://www.africanmoviesnews.com/App_Webservices/homepost.php?min=0&max=15)

and my `webview` code is

```
//newsContent contains the json string after parsing.

  String all="<html><body>"+newsContent+"</body></html>";

                 tv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
                 tv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
                 tv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
                 tv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
                 WebSettings webSettings = tv.getSettings();
                 tv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
                 webSettings.setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.NORMAL);

                 tv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,all, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: Can you show us your json and code?

Comment: @ambrish : I have edited my question.Please see it. As I am working on a bit big project, I cant show the whole code here.

Comment: I am sure Json tag will not work properly in WebView

Comment: @Sameer: Dude there must be some way to achieve this.The same json file works well in iPhone webview.

Comment: Have you tried this tv.loadurl(all, "text/html", "UTF-8") ?

Comment: @Sameer: Yep.I have tried the following methods to load the url,
 tv.loadurl(all, "text/html", "UTF-8");
 tv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,all, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
tv.loadData(all, "text/html","utf-8");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies with "\r\n" in your json data. Look like \r\n work only if they are wrapped in  tag. Easy solution would be replace \r\n with 
 tag.

`String all="<html><body>"+newsContent.replace("\r\n", "<br/>")+"</body></html>";`

Comment: yeah you are right.Already I have solved it but anyways I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @User_2013 mind posting your answer I am stuck in this too and this answer is not working for me

Comment: @IllegalArgument: This answer is based on the context of my question.If you can explain your problem, then we can help you.

Comment: @User_2013 I am receiving response like "i am \r\n a \r\n <br/> <p> subash </p>" it can be anything with html tags and \r\n replacing \r\n like above is not an option in my case because users can be allowed to type \r\n

Comment: @IllegalArgument:`WebView` reads `\r\n` as a simple string but I want to treat as a breakline so I replaced `\r\n` with `<br>`.

Comment: @User_2013 I know that I am working on a messaging app that is present in android iphone and web. So changing this in the server is not possible. I wanted to do something in the android webview itself but it seems there is no direct way to do this anyways thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = "<html><body style=\"text-align:justify\"> %s </body></Html>";
String data = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ac quam risus, at tempus justo. Sed dictum rutrum massa eu volutpat. Quisque vitae hendrerit sem.";
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
webView.loadData(String.format(text, data), "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Below works. There should be double slash \r\n

```
String all=""+newsContent.replace("\\r\\n", "
")+"";
```